# Displaying Month Name Instead of Month Number SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, format

I have a select statement where I am pulling the date. Say my date in the table is `2014-12-25`, I want this to actually return `December 2015`. Is there a function that SQL has that can do this in a clean way? Here is my select:

```
 select a.[amount] AS 'Amount', a.[Date] AS 'Month'

 FROM [myFirstTable] a
 left join [mySecondTable] b on a.[ID] = b.[ID]
 left join [myThirdTable] c on c.[code] = b.[code]

 where c.[myName] = 'John Doe'
```

I would like this to return the `amount` and `month name and year`, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174395.aspx)** function

> Returns a character string that represents the specified datepart of
>   the specified date

```
select a.[amount] AS Amount, 
       DATENAME(Month,a.[Date]) AS [Month],
       Year(a.[Date]) as Year

 FROM [myFirstTable] a
 left join [mySecondTable] b on a.[ID] = b.[ID]
 left join [myThirdTable] c on c.[code] = b.[code]

 where c.[myName] = 'John Doe'
```

or if you want the result in single column then use this.

```
DATENAME(Month,a.[Date]) +' '+ convert(varchar(4),Year(a.[Date])) As Month_Year
```

Comment: This works great, one more question... Is there a way to concatenate the two columns together. So like October 2015 in one column?